# How do I add an endpoint to my Django backend to run a python script?

Tags: python, heroku, django-rest-framework

I currently have a Django backend deployed in Heroku, and I also have a Python script that contains code to return the items with the highest number of mentions in chosen subreddits. It is noted the items are returned in tuple form (item, number of mentions) in a list. I would like to integrate the Python script into the backend as an API endpoint, such that the frontend can call the Python script on demand and in particular, supply user-defined input into the Python script (eg: which subreddit to scrape). Hence, for this reason, runscript in Django-extensions will not be suitable. How should I go about achieving my aim? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

The main function in my Python script looks like this:

```
#reddit is a Reddit instance in praw
#subname is name of subreddit to scrape from
#active_stocks is a dictionary of currently active stocks
#set default time limit as "day" to return all posts within the day itself
#set default limit as None so that all posts are returned
def track_mentions_in_past_24_hours(reddit,subname,active_stocks,time_filter="day",limit=None):
#main body of code is omitted
#returns dictionary of stocks with key value pair as (stock,number of mentions)
    return active_stocks
```

Comment: How about modifying the script, so it can be used programmatically? It's easier to import a function from the script and call it in Django than to deal with launching separate Python processes.

Comment: @bgfvdu3w thank you for the reply! Just wondering, do you mind elaborating on the modifying the script part for programmatic use? I am not quite sure what you mean by that

Comment: If you edit your question to include the script or an example with a similar interface,  it'll be easier to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: @bgfvdu3w hi I have added in a summarised version of the main function in my Python script for reference; in essence the function returns a dictionary, which I intend to get through a call to the backend API

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled using `@api_view(['GET'])`.

You could wrap the function with a decorator and integrate it with URLs.

```
# Imports 
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response


def track_mentions_in_past_24_hours(reddit,subname,active_stocks,time_filter="day",limit=None):
    # ...
    return active_stocks

@api_view(['GET'])
def script_runner(request):
    data = track_mentions_in_past_24_hours(reddit,subname,active_stocks,time_filter="day",limit=None)
    return Response(data)
```

And that's how you can set up the endpoint that will be callable from the front-end app.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('script/', views.script_runner),
]
```

For more details: [Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#wrapping-api-views)

Comment: Hi I tried your method and I get a ResponseException; just to check do you have any idea why?

Comment: Try to return your data in the form list, like dict appended into the list instead of tuples.

Comment: Hi I tried your method where I have a list of dictionaries and I still get a ResponseException